# CombinedChart using MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using a ListView to display a group of charts that get the data from a hosted server. I am using the MPAndroidChart library, and have successfully used all the charts except the CombinedChart and the PieChart. I tried looking for documentation on both, but still was unable to understand these chart implementations. Can anyone please explain to me the working of these two charts : 1) CombinedChart 2) PieChart. Also in combined chart we can pass line and bar data, but how do I add these two datasets to the chart. As per my understanding, I can do it by creating a CombinedChartData object. But I am not able to do it as the application is crashing causing a NullPointerException. I have shown my code below for reference :

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity2);
    combinedChart=(CombinedChart)findViewById(R.id.combined_chart);

    ArrayList<String> labels = getLabels();
    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>(getEntries());
    ArrayList<BarEntry> entries1 = new ArrayList<>(getEntries1());
    LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(entries,"Line Data");
    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(entries1,"Bar Data");
    barDataSet.setColor(0);

    CombinedData combinedData = new CombinedData(labels);
    combinedData.addDataSet(lineDataSet);
    combinedData.addDataSet(barDataSet);

    combinedChart.setData(combinedData);
    combinedChart.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the example:

**CombinedChart**: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/CombinedChartActivity.java

What you do is create your `LineData` and `BarData` object and then set those to the `CombinedData`. It's all in the example.
What you did cannot work since you never ever added the "combineddatasets" to some kind of data object that is then set for the chart.

```
CombinedData data = new CombinedData(yourLabels);
data.setData(generateLineData());
data.setData(generateBarData());

mChart.setData(data);
```

**PieChart**: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/PieChartActivity.java

You should find everything you need there.

Comment: That did help. I have made changes to the code and added the edited code to the question. Even now the project crashes.

Comment: Error :      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference